# PHP Variables Scope

Tags: php, variables, scope

file name **myServices.php**

```
<?php
   $gender = 'MALE';
?>
```

in another file lets say **file.php**

```
    include "myServices.php"

    $name = 'SAM';
    $age  = '23';
?>

<!--after some more HTML code-->
<?php

    $gender = 'FEMALE';        
    $name = 'ELENA';
    //Question:
    //In the above statements are there new variables created or the 
    //previous variables are reassigned new values

?>
```

Comment: You might want to take the question out of the code block, I had a really hard time finding it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The previous variables are reassigned new values.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just like you have it listed, then the `$name` and `$gender` variable's values are replaced with "ELENA"  and "FEMALE"

Why don't you try, `echo $name;`, `echo $gender;`

Answer (score 1):

As Codeacula said,  those variables will be overwritten.  The opening and closing PHP tags do not define scope.  Variables are in what's called the global scope unless they are inside of a function or class.  Global methods are as the name implies available, and can be overwritten inside functions and classes

When a variable is inside of a function then that variable is only available inside of that function unless it is prepended with the keyword `global`.

A quick search on google will give you more information on variable scope.